# Blender 2.80 - Select Multiple Objects Not Working

Tags: objects, selection-tools, origin

I tried to select multiple objects using in select box mode, but it is only selecting the active object (the one that the origin point mark is showing).

What will be the cause? Is that bug or is there something that may be I did wrong with the setting?

Comment: I think I have the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @Ripityom No. I even submitted bug report and still no one know the solution.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the report @KeepMove?

Comment: @brockmann Here you go https://developer.blender.org/T59741

Comment: I have this same problem - I just use lasso instead.